# Lit-Element - Can't get Id of item from Object

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

I am learning lit-element and have run into a small problem I am trying to setup the ability to remove an Item from my list but I am unable to get the id of my Item it is coming across as undefined when I test it with console.log. I have three components the add-item.js which adds items to the list that is working fine. app.js is the main component that handles the auto refresh of the page aswell as the main rendering of the page this is where I have the event listeners for the addItem and the removeItem. Then I have todo-item component which is where I have the object that I am trying to get the ID for the remove functionality. Im at a loss at what I am doing wrong here and was hoping some one could take a look and point me in the right direction 
here is the code so far .

````
add-item.js

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';

class AddItem extends LitElement{

static get properties(){
    return{
        todoList: Array,
        todoItem: String
    }
}

constructor(){
    super();
    this.todoItem = '';
}

inputKeypress(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        e.target.value="";
        this.onAddItem();
    }else{
        this.todoItem = e.target.value;
    }
}

onAddItem(){
    if(this.todoItem.length > 0){
            let storedTodoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo- 
list')); 
            storedTodoList = storedTodoList === null ? [] : storedTodoList;

            storedTodoList.push({
                id: new Date().valueOf(),
                item: this.todoItem,
                done: false
            });

            localStorage.setItem('todo-list', 
JSON.stringify(storedTodoList));
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('addItem',{
                bubbles: true,
                composed: true,
                detail: {
                    todoList: storedTodoList
                }
            }));
            this.todoItem = '';
    }
}

render(){
    return html `
    <div>
        <input value=${this.todoItem}
        @keyup="${(e) => this.inputKeypress(e)}">
        </input>
        <button @click="${() => this.onAddItem()}">Add Item</button>
    </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('add-item', AddItem)
```

app.js

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
import './add-item';
import './list-items';

class TodoApp extends LitElement{

static get properties(){
    return{
        todoList: Array
    }
}

constructor(){
    super();
    let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo-list'));
    this.todoList = list === null ? [] : list;

}

firstUpdated(){
    this.addEventListener('addItem', (e) => {
        this.todoList = e.detail.todoList;
    });
    this.addEventListener('removeItem', (e) => {
        let index = this.todoList.map(function(item) {return 
item.id}).indexOf(e.detail.itemId);
        this.todoList.splice(index, 1);
        this.todoList = _.clone(this.todoList);
        localStorage.setItem('todo-list', JSON.stringify(this.todoList));
    })
}

render(){
    return html `
    <h1>Hello todo App</h1> 
    <add-item></add-item>  
    <list-items .todoList=${this.todoList}></list-items>     
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('todo-app', TodoApp)
```

todo-item.js

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';

class TodoItem extends LitElement{
static get properties(){
    return{
        todoItem: Object
    }
}

constructor(){
    super();
    this.todoItem = {};
}

onRemove(id){
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('removeItem',{
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
        detail:{
            itemId: id
        }
    }));
}

render(){
    console.log(this.todoItem.id);
    return html `<li>${this.todoItem}</li>
    <button @click="${() => 
this.onRemove(this.todoItem.id)}">Remove</button>`;
  }
}

customElements.define('todo-item', TodoItem);
```
````

I am looking to get the Id of the item so that I can remove it from the list for example if i have 5 items, one, two , three , four, five and I click the button to remove the third Item it should be removed and the list updated with the remaining items .. right now it is deleting the items but it is the last one on the list which is what I do not want to happen.

Looking forward to some help on this so that I can move forward with the project 
thank you .

Answer (score 0):

The issues has been resolved,

I was not supplying the entire array, just one element. After fixing the code I was able to get the Id of the object and move forward with my project as expected.